# Prune BTRFS incremental snapshots

Tags: btrfs, snapshot

I'm pretty new to BTRFS. I managed to do a readonly snapshot of my system and send/receive it to an external drive (snapshotting it again as rw so I can even boot it): so far so good.
I know that, in order to do incremental snapshots, I have to tell which is the last previous one: btrfs, of course, needs to know what snapshot it should link the current one to (to save disk space). I also understand that the previous snapshot must exist on the external drive too (they have the same ID) if I want to backup to it incrementally. Crystal clear. The whole story is vey well explained here:
https://fedoramagazine.org/btrfs-snapshots-backup-incremental/

I've read somewhere that if I delete a snapshot in the chain, all the subsequent snapshots are given new IDs: this makes me think that, if I leave on my internal drive just the last prevuous snapshot, I won't be able to join the chain on the external drive anymore. Is it correct? How can I manage to keep all my incremental snapshots on the external drive while having just the last one on the internal?

Comment: The question is not clear to me at all. I am diong incremental backups for years. I don't have any "chains". I have a snapshot of @ called @BACKUP. I also have @-BACKUP on another HDD. When I want to do another backup, I create another shapshot @-BACKUP-new and send it to the HDD with `btrfs send -p /mnt/@-BACKUP /mnt/@-BACKUP-new`. After it is finished, I rename `@-BACKUP-new` to `@-BACKUP`. As simpe as that. I can post a script on how it is done.

Comment: An incremental snapshot saves only the data changed, while all the rest, unchanged, refers the previous snapshot to save disk space

Comment: You need to have two subvolumes on a disk you are doing backup from. The current subvolume and the last snapshot. It is still not clear to me what is the problem. And there is no problem with disk space. Data is not duplicated.

Comment: The problem raises when you want to have many snapshots on one disk only: purging the old snapshots changes subvolumes IDs.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and give an example. The ID is not important.

Comment: I read again your sample code. It seems to me (please, correct me if I'm wrong) that you don't have chains beacause you have just one snapshot (in fact you rename it, at the end). What I'm doing, instead, is keeping an history like Time Machine does on macOS: that's the "chain".

Comment: Now it is clear enough. Please re-write the question and explain all this, better with examples. I or somebody else will be able to answer. Still not everything is clear to me still. ANd explain cleared what you want to achieve.

Comment: Anyway IDs are not important. They do change with my method and there are no problems.

Comment: If you are 100% sure of that, you can amswer my question and I'll accept it. Is it possible to know how can btrfs link to the correct previous snap on the destination drive if the ID is different? I mean... does it just match the path of the "-p" argument looking for a subvolume having the same path on the destination...? Really?

Comment: It is looking for the path. ID is not stored anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To properly answer your question it is important to first explain a bit how `btrfs send/receive` works. From the [BTRFS wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#What_is_the_difference_between_-c_and_-p_in_send.3F):

> It's easiest to understand if you look at what receive does. Receive takes a stream of instructions, creates a new subvolume, and uses the instructions to modify that subvolume until it looks like the one being sent.

In the case of the initial send `btrfs send` produces a data stream with instructions for `btrfs receive` to re-create the subvolume on the new disk - i.e. basically telling it: *create directory `foo`; create file `foo/bar`; put the following content into `foo/bar`*.

In the case of an incremental send `btrfs send` will compare the snapshot you want to send with the parent specified with `-p` and will produce a stream with only the difference between those two subvolumes. `btrfs receive` will then first create a new snapshot from the parent subvolume - which therefore must exist on the receiving side - and modify that snapshot according to the instructions stream - i.e. *move `foo/bar` to `bar`; delete `foo/`; update `bar` with following content; ...*

`btrfs receive` identifies the correct subvolume to take a snapshot from by its UUID. You can see the UUIDs of a subvolume with [`btrfs subvolume show`](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-subvolume#SUBCOMMAND):

- each subvolume has a unique *UUID*
- if it is a snapshot of another subvolume it will reference it via its *Parent UUID*
- if it was created by `btrfs receive` it has the *Received UUID* of the original subvolume

So all you need to do an incremental send is the subvolume you want to send and a "parent" subvolume that already exists on the receiving side.
BTRFS does not care about any contiguous "chain" or something and deleting a subvolume won't change the IDs of another subvolume.

To work *reliably* though you should respect the following:

- do not modify subvolumes after `btrfs send` - neither on the sending nor receiving side - but [keep them `ro`](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-property#SUBCOMMAND) all the time.
- only use appropriate subvolumes as send parent, i.e. they should be snapshots of one another or have a common parent

Comment: A perfect answer!